# В Postgres выбрать 10 строк и чтобы в этот набор точно попадала строка у определенным условием

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть одна таблица `public.kit`, допустим, на 1000 строк с полями `name` и `code`.

| name | code |
| --- | --- |
| qqqq | q11 |
| wwww | w21 |
| eeee | e22 |
| rrrr | r23 |

...

Мне необходимо выбрать 10 строк (любых) и чтобы в этот набор точно попадала строка с условием `code = 'e22'`
Т.е. запрос что-то вроде:

```sql
SELECT k.*
FROM public.kit k
WHERE k.code IN ('e22', SELECT code FROM public.kit LIMIT 10)
```

(такой запрос, естественно, работать не будет)
Можно ли реализовать это условие в одном запросе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `UNION ALL + LIMIT`:

```
SELECT k.*
FROM public.kit k
WHERE k.code = 'e22'
UNION ALL
(SELECT k.*
FROM public.kit k
WHERE k.code != 'e22'
LIMIT 9)
```

или так:

```
SELECT k.*
FROM public.kit k
WHERE k.code = 'e22'
   OR k.code in (
      select code
      from public.kit
      where code != 'e22'
      LIMIT 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT {columnset}
FROM {tableset}
ORDER BY {criteria}, {another expressions}
LIMIT {limit}
```

В данном конкретном случае

```sql
SELECT k.*
FROM public.kit k
ORDER BY k.code = 'e22' DESC, RAND() 
LIMIT 10
```